# Tailwindcss does not generate all classes

Tags: css, styles, tailwind-css

i know tailwindcss cli creates only the used class of the project in according with "content" options in tailwins.config.js.

but... is there a way to evitate this optimization (not considering content options and the written code) and let it creates ALL classes in according with the rest of configuration file???

I would like to create a styles lib by tailwind but not on a specific project. I would like create that lib in an angular library to share it then. Any ideas?

UPDATE: i found a command "tailwindcss-cli build -o <output.file>" that create all css from config. It create a very big file but i ma not so confident with it. I don't understand is tailwindcss-cli and tailwindcss are the same. I seems no in fact i can't have the same result using tailwindcss build bue if i call help on both cli i get the same.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel, you have to run:

```
npx tailwindcss-cli build -o public/css/app.css
```

It will generate all styles (3MB file size). After finishing your application, you can run again:

```
npm run dev
```

to remove all unused styles, as it will take only used styles from your php code.